# I want to calculate distance of child latitude, longitude and school latitude, longitude

Tags: geoserver

I have school latitude=54.2323 and longitude=76.2323 and child latitude=32.2323 and longitude=54.2323. school radius I have taken 500 meter.

I want to make a circle for school using that radius and make one center point.

I want to find child is inside the the school or not using child latitude and longitude.

Comment: Do you have WPS extension to your geoserver? Do you have any other tools available?